# Webcam not showing up in picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to use the device webcam to scan a QR code and display out the content correctly, however it is able to run successfully, yet the webcam is not showing up.

Below is the screenshot of the outpage page, in which the picturebox which is supposed to display the webcam is empty.
[image]

My code for the entire windows form is as below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        FilterInfoCollection filterInfoCollection;
        VideoCaptureDevice captureDevice;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            filterInfoCollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo filterInfo in filterInfoCollection)
                cboDevice.Items.Add(filterInfo.Name);
            cboDevice.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    
    private void btnRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        captureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoCollection[cboDevice.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        captureDevice.NewFrame += CaptureDevice_NewFrame;
        captureDevice.Start();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void CaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

        //throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }

    private void UserControl1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (captureDevice.IsRunning)
            captureDevice.Stop();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
            Result result = barcodeReader.Decode((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
            if (result != null)
            {
                txtContent.Text = result.ToString();
                timer1.Stop();
                if (captureDevice.IsRunning)
                    captureDevice.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am unsure if there is now an error with my code, or if there is any permission that needs to be given from my device as I have already given full read-write access to this file.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `CaptureDevice_NewFrame` and `timer1_Tick` does the breakpoint get hit?

Comment: I have tried inserting a breakpoint and nothing seems to be happening at all.

Comment: Check device manager for name of USB camera.  Then compare to cboDevice.SelectedIndex

Comment: If the timer tick breakpoint is not being hit, that means you haven't assigned a callback from the timer component to your tick function.  If you set a breakpoint on `btnRead_Click` does that get hit when you press Read?

Comment: I have checked the device manager, and as I am only using the intergrated webcam as the only camera device here, that doesnt seem to be the problem @jdweng

Comment: Can I know how to assign a callback from the timer component to tick function? I'm a little confused on that. And similarly, the breakpoint only shows a red circle when it's set on the  ```btnRead_Click```

Comment: When you created the timer component, did you drag and drop it from the toolbox?  If so, single click on the component and look at its events, the 'tick' event should have the name of your tick function.

Answer (score 0):

Check your btnStart_Click [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNeoa.png)

Comment: *"Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."* - check [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please provide some explanations on how this answer's the OP's question.